# Does this inequality imply what I think it does?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, $$

$$g(x) - \epsilon < \underset{[x, x+h]}{\inf g} \leq g(x)$$

Does this imply that $\underset{[x, x+h]}{\inf g} = g(x)$?

Comment: Indeed, since $x - \varepsilon < y \leq x$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: Could you help me understand why that's the case?

Comment: Suppose $y < x$. Take $\varepsilon = x - y$. Then $x - \varepsilon = y \not < y$.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you. So you conclude that x<= y, right? And then since you also know that y <= x, your only solution is that x=y?

Comment: Yep, you've got it.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I wish I could come up with a more descriptive title for this question. It’s not great, but at the same time I think it’s as good as can be done.